# How to find two lines of a string based on a word from strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string

Hi i am working on a RoR project. i have a string in my params. Based on a predefined word i have to find two lines of a string.

String:-

```
 "\"FileParseExitCode\":1,\n\"ParsedText\":SUPA IGA WATERFORD \nCnr Manning g Kent St \nKarawara WA 6152 \nPin: 08 9200 4211 Fax: oe 9200 4212 \nlax Invoice \n138 932 466 \n12/04/2018 PM \nScot User 12 \nAUSSIE NAT SPROG WATER 1.5L $0.99 \nTOTAL \nMaster \nYou saved: $0.08 "
```

Here i have a word "6152" based on this word i need to find the paragraph of this line which is:

```
\nKarawara WA 6152
```

And the paragragh before "\nKarawara WA 6152":-

```
\nCnr Manning g Kent St
```

So basically i want the two lines with a predefined word. My word is "6152" i want to get the paragraph:-

```
\nCnr Manning g Kent St \nKarawara WA 6152
```

Please help me to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't why you've received so many downvotes but you clearly need to improve the statement of the question.

Comment: I'm guessing, but the downvotes are probably because it's accepted practice here to try doing it first and to come here with at least one attempt, rather than asking for help writing the first implementation.

Answer (score 1):

If `str` is your string, you could use a regular expression to extract the two consecutive lines.

```
target = "6152"

r = /
    \n         # match end of line
    [^\n]*     # match zero or more chars other than \n
    \n         # match end of line
    [^\n]*     # match zero or more chars other than \n
    (?<!\d)    # do not match a digit (negative lookbehind)
    #{target}  # match the target string
    (?!\d)     # do not match a digit (negative lookahead)
    [^\n]*     # match zero or more chars other than \n
    /x         # free-spacing regex definition mode
  # => /
    \n         # match end of line
    [^\n]*     # match zero or more chars other than \n
    \n         # match end of line
    [^\n]*     # match zero or more chars other than \n
    (?<!\d)    # do not match a digit (negative lookbehind)
    6152       # match the target string
    (?!\d)     # do not match a digit (negative lookahead)
    [^\n]*     # match zero or more chars other than \n
    /x

str[r]
  #=> "\nCnr Manning g Kent St \nKarawara WA 6152 "
```

The negative lookbehind (`(?<!\d)`) and negative lookahead (`(?!\d)`) prevent a match if `target` contains `"6152"` but that is preceded or followed by one or more digits.